# Docusign API - Fixed Width Setting for Text Tabs/Tags

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the Docusign API and trying to set the Fixed Width Flag which wraps the Text that is present in the Text Tab/Box similar to the Docusign UI when using the SandBox.. The fixed width is responsible for the text box to not exceed the document width, and it also changes a single line text box into a multi line text box once it reaches the width of the document.

How could i do this with the Docusign API?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using below JSON for Text Tab:

```
{
    "textTabs": [
        {
            "tabLabel": "Sample Text",
            "disableAutoSize": true,
            "maxLength": 100,
            "width": 134,
            "height": 33,
            "pageNumber": 1,
            "documentId": "1",
            "xPosition": 163,
            "yPosition": 73
        }
    ]
}
```